# Selenium wait until method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am new to using Selenium and am trying to work out how to use the wait until method on the website booking.com, to wait for the dropdown options to be visible as in the image.
[image]

This is the code I am working with:

```
driver.get('http://booking.com')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ss').send_keys("London")
WebDriverWait(driver,1).until('PLEASE SUGGEST WHAT TO INPUT')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//*[@id="frm"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]""").click()
```

Using the chrome inspector, I cannot see any clear selector or element to use in the parentheses for the until method.  When i right-click on the visible options and click 'Copy selector' I just get this:

```
#frm > div:nth-child(8) > div > div.c-autocomplete.sb-destination > ul.c-autocomplete__list.sb-autocomplete__list.-visible > li.c-autocomplete__item.sb-autocomplete__item.sb-autocomplete__item--city
```

Please can someone suggest what I need to do here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get('http://booking.com')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ss').send_keys("London")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search_hl_name")))
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class ='search_hl_name']")[1].click() // you can use relative xpath in place of absolute one, replace index value at [1] with 0-4 which ever you want to select
```

As rightly mentioned by Andersson you need to increase the timeout

Comment: That's great thanks. How do you go about finding the CSS-SELECTOR or XPATH using the inspector/web dev tools in Chrome (or Firefox)? And how do you know whether it is an absolute or relative XPATH?

Comment: If you start xpath with // and put only small values to locate element then its relative xpath and in absolute xpath you start with /than/x/x/x/ something like this which traverse the html . see this link it will provide you some info. http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: Thanks, great post by the way, I have it bookmarked now.

Comment: Now I am having trouble clicking on dates. Say if I want to click todays date I have tried: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td[@class="c2-day c2-day-s-today"]').click()  but it does not do anything. How do I find the XPath for this?

Comment: ("//span[@class ='c2-day-inner' and text()='29']")[1] change this value 29 with date you want to select and [0] or [1] based on first month or second month of view. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working. This is the code I tried: 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="c2-day-inner" and text="29"]'[0]).click()  I get the following error message: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/" is: [object HTMLDocument]. It should be an element.

Comment: sorry this is actually what i tried: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//span[@class ='c2-day-inner' and text()='29']")[0]).click()

Comment: inplace of find_element use : driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//span[@class ='c2-day-inner' and text()='29']"))[0].click() because we are doing indexing which required multiple elements

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wait until one of drop-down options become clickable with [`ExpectedConditions`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ss').send_keys("London")
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[@class="c-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item--city sb-autocomplete__item--two-lines "]')))
```

Note that second argument you pass in `WebDriverWait()` is timeout (in seconds) and `1` second might be not enough to wait for expectation met

To select required option you might use more verbose relative `XPath` instead of absolute one:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li//b[text()="Central London"]').click()
```

This should select option with bold text "**Central London**". Just replace `"Central London"` with appropriate value to select another option

Comment: What value would I put to have a relative XPath instead of an absolute one, if I wanted to write the code so that it would click the first option for any city that was entered?

Comment: `'//li[@class="c-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item--city sb-autocomplete__item--two-lines "]'` is `XPath` to match the first option